# Wordpress CSS not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My WordPress themes are not working. My WordPress is 4.9.3, everything was working fine until the server admin moved the directory. So I basically, edited the DB home and site URL values, and the website is functioning, except the themes. All of them I even tried the Twenty FifteenVersion and it's not working too. What is not working exactly is the CSS, although when I check through to inspect if the files are loaded, and when I download them they are correct. So the themes are sort of HTML only and messed up. I checked/corrected the file permissions, and still, it's not working.

Comment: After having moved the directory, have you also changed the pointed directory of the domain in your hosting admin panel ?

Answer (score 1):

When you move your WP to another folder, you have to change de the post content too.
You can do that with this:

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'www.old.com', 'www.new.com');

Please! Make a backup first ;)

Also make sure your **Permalink** is ok:

Go to **Settings** » **Permalink** and click **Save Changes** to ensure that all post links are working fine.

Good luck! :)

Comment: I already did that using "Velvet Blues Update URLs" plugin, also I saved the Permalink. I tried another experiment, which is to start from scratch, and surprisingly, also the Twenty Fifteen theme was messed up.

Comment: maybe the ssl certificate then?
It could block your css files. Try change http to https on link tags.

Comment: I do not have SSL certificate on the domain. However, I am redirecting to an IP address with some other sites that do (Its a university server).

Comment: After displaying warning in my console I realized that I'm getting this error message "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/x-download: "<URL>"" ,,,

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the exported Database SQL file in an editor and find/replace every instance of the previous URL with the new URL (i.e. http://www.your_new_domain.com/ replacing http://www.your_old_domain.com/. Then transfer it to the new server.

The reason: Wordpress saves all URLs / links etc. with absolute filepaths in the database. These filepaths need to be changed in order for the site to work on another server.

Plus you need to make sure the settings in the `wp-config.php` file are updated (mainly server access settings)

Comment: I already did that using "Velvet Blues Update URLs" plugin, also I saved the Permalink. I tried another experiment, which is to start from scratch, and surprisingly, also the Twenty Fifteen theme was messed up.